# Numerically integrate using SciPy library in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have an acceleration vs time graph like this:
[image]

I am using SciPy library and cumtrapz function to get the velocity vs time graph: [image]

The code snippet:
`velocity_int = sp.integrate.cumtrapz(acceleration, x=time, initial=0)`

As you can say the actual velocity curve and the one from integration looks very similar. However, when I use the same method to find the displacement, I am not able to get the appropriate curve: `displacement_int = sp.integrate.cumtrapz(velocity_int, x=time, initial=0)`

[image]

I am not able to understand the reason for this. The velocity curve does take a sharp turn there, but as far as I understand, integration does not cause any trouble with sharp corners in a function. Maybe, the sharp corner is causing some problem to the numerical scheme. Please help me with some ideas.

I tried to limit down the y-axis limits between +10 and -10 and found the curves with lots of ups and downs:
[image]
Maybe this is the reason for the error in the result. Is there any way to achieve the displacement curve, maybe using higher models of integration?

Edit: There were some issues with the scaling and units, but that has been resolved and curves updated. So units shouldn't cause any trouble now.

Comment: Have you checked your units for the `x` vs `t` graph?

Comment: And also all the other graphs. With an additional factor 0.1 from a to v and from v to x the scales should match.

Comment: @JuanE. Checked the units, they are correct. However, seems like the curve is matching to some extent, it must be some issue with scaling. I have updated the displacement curve removing the y limits to see the full scale picture. Thanks!!

Comment: yep.. wrong scale = wrong units

Comment: @JuanE.: I have updated the question with all the corrections now. Also, I tried to limit down the y-axes of the curve to understand what happens between 0 to 5th  second. Please have a look and see if you have any ideas. Thanks!!